# add and remove string to image tag

Tags: php

I have a variable containing some HTML, I want to update each `img` tag by adding the domain to its source if missing

```
 $description="<div>Text<img src='some/image'></img></div>";
 $description=preg_replace('/<img([^>]*)src=["\']([^"\'\\/][^"\']*)["\']/', '<img\1src="http://domain.com/\2"',$description);
```

#### output

```
<div>Text<img src="http://domain.com/some/image"></img></div>
```

This works fine, but after some process I want to remove the domain name from the `src` attribute (I want to do the opposite).

I tried using `preg_replace` but it didnt work proprely.

Comment: `preg_replace('~http://domain.com/~', '', $description);`

Comment: Thanx but I want only to target the img src because this will remove the domain name from the rest of the html also.

Comment: Then this might work?: `preg_replace('~img src="http://domain.com/~', 'img src="', $description);`

Comment: @TomRegner why not posting as an answer confidentially so that we can also try

Comment: @TomRegner Bingo, it works you can post your answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment above, this is the quickest solution that came to mind:

```
preg_replace('~img src="http://domain.com/~', 'img src="', $description);
```

Note that using the tilde `~` as regular expression delimiter reduces the 'leaning toothpick syndrome' you get by adhering to the customary `/`

Comment: I was writing the answer :)